# My Rigid body simulation doesn't work as I want it to

Tags: rigid-body-simulation

So I made a pixel mesh that is made out of many boxes and I want them to fall and break when they hit the ground but they break then falls. What settings should I change?[image][image: I want it to fall first then break] I want it to fall first and break on impact when it hits the ground. My settings are on the right of the image.

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was that I was applying rigid body to all of the cubes at once which was giving me a different simulation. The solution is you have to apply rigid body to one cube and make sure you get the reaction you want and then apply copy from active and then bake it and it should work fine. It works great for me. You have to keep in mind that the collision shape will cause a different simulation depending on what shape you used.